Multivariate t-test equivalent - control versus intervention
Suppose there were two groups characterised by the same dependent and independent variables.

Dependent variable = time to treatment initiation - continuous.
Independent variable = point of care test - Y/N.

In the univariate context above, an unpaired t-test for evaluating mean difference between groups seems appropriate (once all the t-test requisites have been established).
However, suppose that you wished to control for risk factor (say, diabetes status, social deprivation etc).
Which model could be used to control for risk and still conduct a t-test between the two groups?
Any help would be appreciated.

A general framework for time until event analysis would be the Cox proportional hazards model. Is this what you mean? You can include any number of risk factors.

Hi @FransRodenburg. Thanks for your response. So, effectively the objective is to (1) evaluate whether there is a statistically different time to treatment across both groups following a point of care test. Hence the t-test. However (2), is it possible to run a Cox type model for two groups adding in risk covariates and evaluate whether time to treatment is different across both groups? If so, could you possibly provide a link to any example R code online, please?

Had a look @FransRodenburg. Thanks for the pointer - the Cox stuff is not something I knew much about beforehand. I'll look into it :)
